# split specific pattern(eg:2 kg rice) from text using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

eg: txt = onion 2 pieces 3 bunch coriander 1/2 kg banana
i want a text in split format given below

onion 2 pieces
3 bunch coriander
1/2 kg banana

I tried this code

```
txt = '2 kg rice onion 2 pieces 1/2 kg banana'
lst1=[]
lst2=[]
for i in range(len(txt)):
    if txt[i][0].isdigit()==True:
        lst2.append(txt[i])
    
    else:
        lst1.append(txt[i])
```

Comment: That's more complicated than you might think. You don't have one consistent pattern to look for (your examples are a mix of `name number unit` and `number unit name`). *"Every three words"* doesn't seem like a safe assumption either.

Comment: I want a output like
2 kg rice \n
onion 2 pieces \n
1/2 kg banana

Comment: Yes, I understand the output you want. What I'm saying is this isn't a straightforward task.

Comment: I know but I want to find item, unit and quantity to make a dataframe

Comment: is there any approach to get the data

Comment: If you have data structure dict or set which contains the products, you might be able to use that as a way to further parse the text stream to identify qty and units